# How to write a webservice?

Tags: web-services

For my iOS app I am going to need a webservice which handels the login and the storage of userdata. For testing purposes I used a simple php file as the login script, it took an email and a password and return a xml response if the login is correct. The general function is quering the database and returning JSON or XML.

Now, I have read a couple of tutorials about webservice and somepeople say that RESTful webservices are the best others say use SOAP. At the moment I don't know how to go on. I need to write a webservice for my app, in whatever language with whatever technologie.

Can you give me any recommendation on what I should use and maybe some good tutorials or something like that?

Comment: This depends on many factors.. What language(s) are you comfortable in? How are you going to host the service? What tools do you have access to?

Comment: I am comfortable in c++,objective-c,java,php and a bit of phyton. For testing purpose I use a small V-Server later the server can be upgraded unlimited.